# How to crop SurfaceView in CameraSource for OCR

Tags: android, camera, surfaceview, crop, textureview

How to crop the SurfaceView for OCR, that OCR would be doing recognition only on the part of the photo, which is in the frame.

I used [this tutorial](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.google.android.gms.vision.text.TextRecognizer)! And for now the whole surface is recognizable. While I want to recognize only part of the whole SurfaceView, as for example in barcodes.

But still, User should have the picture of full surface.

I tried to use TextureView, but it's not compatible with CameraSouce.

private void startCameraSource() {

```
    //Create the TextRecognizer
    final TextRecognizer textRecognizer = new TextRecognizer.Builder(getApplicationContext()).build();

    if (!textRecognizer.isOperational()) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Detector dependencies not loaded yet");
    } else {

        //Initialize camerasource to use high resolution and set Autofocus on.
        mCameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(getApplicationContext(), textRecognizer)
                .setFacing(CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_BACK)
                .setRequestedPreviewSize(1280, 1024)
                .setAutoFocusEnabled(true)
                .setRequestedFps(2.0f)
                .build();

        /*
          Add call back to SurfaceView and check if camera permission is granted.
          If permission is granted we can start our cameraSource and pass it to surfaceView
         */
        surfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                try {

                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
                            Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                        return;
                    }
                    mCameraSource.start(surfaceView.getHolder());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                mCameraSource.stop();
            }
        });

        //Set the TextRecognizer's Processor.
        textRecognizer.setProcessor(new Detector.Processor<TextBlock>() {
            @Override
            public void release() {
            }

            /**
             * Detect all the text from camera using TextBlock and the values into a stringBuilder
             * which will then be set to the textView.
             * */
            @Override
            public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<TextBlock> detections) {
                final SparseArray<TextBlock> items = detections.getDetectedItems();

                if (items.size() != 0) {
                    mTextView.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                            for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
                                TextBlock item = items.valueAt(i);

                                stringBuilder.append(item.getValue());
                                stringBuilder.append("\n");
                            }

                            String detectedext = stringBuilder.toString().replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "");
                            detectedext = detectedext.replaceAll("\\D+", "");
                            String comparisonResult = queryEquiNoDatabase(detectedext);
                            System.out.println(detectedext);
                            if (comparisonResult == null) {
                                textViewRectangle.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textview_border_detecting);
                            } else {
                                textViewRectangle.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textview_border_end);
                                Intent intentAfterCameraScan = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TransformerBoxActivity.class);
                                intentAfterCameraScan.putExtra("equino", comparisonResult);
                                intentAfterCameraScan.putExtra("isOcrLast", true);
                                createEffect(intentAfterCameraScan, 1500);
                                textRecognizer.release();
                            }

                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The picture of the activity:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIy1e.jpg

What is actually recognized:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHUxx.jpg

And I expect to recognize only thing which are inside the borders
For now the whole surface is applied for recognition.

Comment: You must rewrite CameraSource, or use a different OCR library, with a mor flexible API

Comment: @AlexCohn Hey. Okey. Do you have an idea which one is good choice?

Comment: It's your choice